# Asking for advice in further Java game development

Tags: java, 2d-games

I have watched many Java toturials, learned some basics Java. About 1month ago, I'm interested in Java game development, learned some basic stuff (control sprite, draw figures, basic collision and etc.). But something in me telling that I doing something wrong.

**So im here asking to expierenced Java developers, what tool/program/plugin should I choose to create Java 2D games properly?** Until now I have used Eclipse.

P.s. sorry for my English, its not my native language.
P.s.s. maybe anyone can recommend any Java book about game development or just about Java?

Comment: Switching from Eclipse is somewhat akin to getting rid of your screwdriver because you are screwing metal instead of wood, with the same screws. Stick with Eclipse, but add the necessary 2d graphics/input libraries to aid your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eclipse, and learn all of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) before you start and not just by watching tutorials on Youtube. I suggest you start with game development by using java2D (awt & swing) then moving on to either Slick2D or libGDX, though I do suggest libGDX because it's still being developed. [Here's an interesting question which you might find useful too](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/what-are-good-games-to-earn-your-wings-with).